# How to responsive table with multiple column using Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I tried to apply bootstrap responsive  with simple columns(4 Columns) it's works in table,but when i used same table with more than 8 columns it's not working so please give me proper solution please!!!!!!!!

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered table-responsive">
    <thead class="btn-primary">
    <tr>    
         <th >YEAR</th>
         <th>EstimatedMid-Year-Populatio</th>
         <th>Infanticide</th>
         <th >Murde</th>
         <th>Rape</th>
         <th>Kidnapping&Abduction</th>
         <th>Abetment Of Suicide</th>
         <th>Child MarriagRestraint Ac</th>
         <th >Other Crimes</th>
         <th>education</th>
         <th>State</th> 
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>1999</td>
    <td>1500</td>
    <td>sssta</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>8</td>
</table>
```

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/content/tables/), I don't think we can decrease or increase the number of columns of a table. However, you can try by using the [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/).